# Can't creat an sh script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

On my Ubuntu 18.04 terminal, I try this:

```
cd home/myusername/bin
cat -n > test
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World"
chmod 755 test
```

Then, when I try to run my script with `sh`, I get:

```
test: 1: test: 1: not found
test: 2: test: 2: not found
```

When I run it with `bash`,  I get:

```
test: line 1: 1: command not found
test: line 2: 2: command not found
```

and when I run it like this `./test`, I get:

```
test: line 1: 1: command not found
test: line 2: 2: command not found
```

I have made sure that `sh` is located in the `bin` directory and also the directory that I created `test` is located in the path variable but it will not do anything if I try to run it with its name.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat -n` places a line number in front of each line, as you can see if you do `cat test` to show the contents of the file you wrote.

The shell does not understand these line numbers and tries to run a program named `1:`, `2:`, etcetera.

Simply omit the `-n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
vincent@idefix:/tmp$ cat << EOF > test
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World"
EOF
```

chmod +x /tmp/test